# How can I see which files I used some days ago?

Tags: filesystem, file, logs, history

I had a telephone conference days three days ago. I took notes while talking and now I can't find them. It could be that I just tipped them into an open document or maybe I created a new one and didn't save it properly or idk... I looked through the last versions of the last docs I used but found nothing.

I still know the exact time I called, so maybe I would remember where I wrote them if I could see which files I used while the call.

Is there any possibility to see which files I used that time? I already tried to look it up on the console but found nothing. And in the device tab, there are only the events of today.

I'd be very happy if someone could help me because these were very important.

Have a nice weekend,

Daniel

Comment: what application did you use to write the notes?

Comment: And which computer / os?

Answer (score 2):

Since you were using an application to take notes, the Finder should have the information about the files you were using. You can use the Finder search (CMD+F) to filter all the files "Last opened", "Last modified" or "Created" on a specific date (i.e.):
[image]

Comment: Hm.. It's a good an idea but I already looked at the last used files and didn't find anything.

But how can I choose the date and get the toolbar under the regular one? Maybe this would help..

PS. It can be that I wrote the notes an deleted them from the document afterwards. I don't know, this didnt happen to me before..

Comment: if you are in the Finder and press CMD+F a finder window is opened (or the current window is modified) to show the "Searching" bar.  You then just click on the first selection menu (usualli initialized with the "Kind" attribute) and choose for example "Last modified date"; the search toolbar then adapts and the second selection menu allows you to select how to specify the date. In some programs, if enought time was elapsed between changes, you can revert to a previous version ("revert to" item in the File menu)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest find any file.
https://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.php

shows date range.
[image]

You can look for content too.
[image]